# doubles in embedded python

Tags: python, python-c-api

So I'm writing a set of C++ classes that run Python scripts. I've gotten code working to run any script I want from a specified directory, and I can pass and return values just fine.

But the one issue I have is I can't seem to find out how to set Python doubles up. 
For example, when I was using long values, I could use "PyLong_AsLong([whatever value I'm trying to convert to a long from a PyObject])" -- but is there a PyDouble_Something in the Python/C API I can use for that?
My google searching has so far turned up nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [PyFloat_AsDouble](http://docs.python.org/c-api/float.html#PyFloat_AsDouble), no?

Comment: Yeah, I just found out about the PyFloat objects and Python using floats as doubles.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer.
I was mistaken, and I thought there were doubles in Python, but there aren't.
I got it to work using a "PyFloat" object, and just converted the double like this:

"PyFloat_FromDouble([the double I wanted as a PyObject])"